# How to Get URL-rewritten Parameter Values in MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, global-variables, asp.net-mvc-routing

For this:

http://example.com/ClubOpeningTool?c=66

I know I can use the controller method parameter or

```
  Request.QueryString["c"];
```

I created a routing rule in Global.asax which transforms the above URL to:
http://example.com/ClubOpeningTool/Index/Club/66

I noticed that `Request.QueryString["c"];` does not work in that case, because the `Request.QueryString[]` array is empty. This seems strange that MVC has no idea of the routing rule that I created when it hydrates the Request.QueryString[] array. Shouldn't it still consider those keys and values *query string values* and put them in the array?

How can I access the rewritten query string params? Is there another global array that they get stored in?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I know I can get the value through the action parameter but I am asking about accessing it via global array as well since Request.QueryString does not work when the URL is rewritten via a routing rule

Answer (score 0):

There is a stark difference between routing and handling parameters. If you setup a route for something, you will need to make sure that the method in your controller is setup to take in the arguments that you are looking for.

If your route looks like the below example.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "HandleClub",
            url: "ClubOpeningTool/Club/{c}",
            defaults: new { controller = "ClubOpeningTool", action = "Club", c = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Notice that I specified that this is going to the ClubOpeningTool and I am passing in c as an optional parameter for the club that I want to open. In order to read "c" though I will need to make sure that my "Club" action that I am calling has c as one of the parameters. If you want it to be optional your club opening controller could look something like this.

```
 public class ClubOpeningToolController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /ClubOpeningTool/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Club(int c = 0)
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

You will probably need to setup a different view for this or return the proper view. But this should at least get ya going.

Keep in mind that Request.QueryString[]; will only contain things in the actual uri's query params. (anything after the ?)